# Unconstrained convex optimization: correlation between dimensionality and Lipschitz constant

Tags: optimization, reference-request, convex-optimization

The author of the [SIAM News article "Optimization Theory and Perspectives on the Field of Machine Learning"](https://sinews.siam.org/Details-Page/optimization-theory-and-perspectives-on-the-field-of-machine-learning) mentions:

> ... For unconstrained convex optimization, GD (*gradient descent*) convergence rates do not depend on the space’s dimensionality. In other words, if we measure a notion of how close we are to the global minimum, convergence rates depend on the function’s properties and the number of descent steps; they are independent of whether a problem has 10 variables or 10 million. Readers might find this dimension-independence surprising, though perhaps there is a “catch” **that practical problems may have a correlation between dimensionality and their Lipschitz constant**.

I was wondering if there are any research papers/reports/studies that support the claim (in bold) that practical optimization problems have a correlation between dimensionality and their Lipschitz constant.

This may be a general study that performs an analysis on a large set of various problems or a narrow application with a dimensionality-Lipschitz constant study. It would be particularly helpful if the study is related to computational electromagnetics, but I am also interested in other domains. A more general optimization theory reference that would justify this [quite intuitive] claim (as optimization is not my main area of expertise) would be also quite welcome.

Comment: Take one of the simplest possible problems - a Poisson equation $\Delta u = f$ with reflecting or periodic boundary conditions (you can frame it as an optimisation problem using the variational formulation if you want). Discretising $\Delta$ with FDM leads to a negative semi-definite matrix $L$. Ignoring the one zero eigenvalue, the condition number of this thing grows with the number of discretisation points, so gradient descent performs worse and worse on larger systems. The latter may be a result of a finer grid or a higher-dimensional problem. The eigenvalues also add up for $n$D.

Comment: @lightxbulb I like the approach of taking a simple example as a starting point, which seems to illustrate the correlation! Would still be interested in some references targeting this topic wider and more elaborate/pedantic.